# Need advice on ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

Hey so I picked up this example for the java docs for ExecutorService. I wanted to confirm the flow of this code, the  Executors.newFixedThreadPool will create a pool of threads(I guess). So the serversocket will wait for a connection and once it acquires one, it starts a thread, so now the poolsize decrease by 1. Once the thread finishes execution, the poolsize will again increment by 1, wont it? Will the thread give up the resources it used?

```
class NetworkService implements Runnable {
 private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
 private final ExecutorService pool;

 public NetworkService(int port, int poolSize)
   throws IOException {
 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
 pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
}

 public void run() { // run the service
 try {
   for (;;) {
     pool.execute(new Handler(serverSocket.accept()));
   }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
   pool.shutdown();
  }
 }
}

class Handler implements Runnable {
 private final Socket socket;
 Handler(Socket socket) { this.socket = socket; }
 public void run() {
  // read and service request on socket
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Once the thread finishes execution, the poolsize will again increment by 1, wont it?

Yes.  The thread will go to take and run the next `Handler`.

> Will the thread give up the resources it used?

Not immediately, no.  Once the `Handler` `run()` method has finished then the `Handler` will go out of scope.  However, you have to wait for the garbage collector to run before the `Handler` instance is released.  This will in turn release `Socket` which then be a candidate for garbage collection itself.

If you want your `Socket` to be released sooner (which I assume is the problem) then that should be done at the end of the `run()` method.  You can call `socket.close()` (and maybe set `socket` to be `null`) in a `finally` block.  Something like the following is recommended:

```
class Handler implements Runnable {
    ...
    public void run() {
       try {
           // read and service request on socket
       } finally {
           // make sure we close the socket when the handler is finishing
           socket.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the threads do is execute *your* `Runnable`s.
So if you need to do any clean after what your task did *you* should do it from your `Runnable`. The pool is just a `Producer`-`Consumer` pattern implementation and is responsible for managing the life-cycle of the threads.
The threads executes the tasks you pass in the queue so in your case, the `socket` is not reused among threads. It's scope is inside the `Runnable`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a fixedThreadPool, yes, the pool size is reduced everytime a task is submitted to the pool & increased once a thread is done running the submitted runnable (or callable).
Submitting more number of runnables to a fixed thread pool will block until any of the threads in the pool are done running their tasks submitted earlier.